# Is there a way to reconstruct an Xcode project file?

Tags: xcode

If the current Xcode project files (all inside the `ProjectName.xcodeproj` folder) are missing after a crash, is there a way to reconstruct it if not relying on git? (the project file is not committed all the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough redundant information elsewhere to completely reconstruct an xcodeproj file, but you can start by making a new one and dragging the source code into it.

Comment: if it is merely creating a new project and then adding files to it, if a human can do this drag and drop task, for sure the computer should be able to be smart enough to do it too... but just that maybe it is not built

Comment: xcode command line tools don't support adding files from the command line. If that's what you need to do, your choices are reverse engineering the xcodeproj structure or AppleScript.