# iOS / xcode: I wasn't given the project file (.xcodeproj), only the source code. How do I build the project?

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to reconstruct an Xcode project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569230/is-there-a-way-to-reconstruct-an-xcode-project-file)

I'm new at ios and xcode. To view the functionality of an app, I'm usually given a project file (.xcodeproj) along with the source code. I double-click the project file and everything opens up nicely in xcode.

This time I wasn't given the project file. I just have a folder that has the source code in it.

How do I take the source code and make a project out of it? I tried Creating a new Xcode project, as well as connecting to a repository, but so far it hasn't been successful. Then again, I'm new at this and not sure what I'm doing. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to create a new project and drag all the files into it?

Comment: @DrummerB: And, yes, that's the answer

Comment: I've been trying to. I create a new project, and then drag the folder of source code into the project. Depending on the options I choose, it either does nothing, or generates numerous errors. This last time I had to force quit xcode.

Answer (score 1):

This [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/020-Start_a_Project/start_project.html) provided by apple should give you a good step by step process to creating a new Project.

Once you have created your project, place all of you header (.h) and main (.m) files and the interface (.xib) files into your Project.

You shouldn't have a problem overall if you have all of the right files, and if the program is correctly built. If you incur more problems after you've done this, then there will most likely be a problem with your files.

Comment: After taking a closer look at the error messages, I can see that adding the files to the project was the solution. You're right about there being problems with the files - there are a number of files missing, which is an entirely different issue. Thanks for the help.